# Nginx Symfony subdirectory configuration

Tags: symfony, nginx, configuration, subdirectory

```
server {
    listen <...:...>;
    server_name <...>;
    root /var/www/html/myserver;

    location /myproject {
        try_files $uri /myproject/web/app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/myproject/web/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass <...php-fpm...>;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    location ~ ^/myproject/web/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass <...php-fpm...>;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

}
```

I can see my project when I trying to go `myserver.com/myproject/web`

I want access to my project at `myserver.com/myproject`.

But this url give 404 (in Symfony):

```
No route found for "GET /myproject/"
```

I added this rewrite rule in my configuration file but its not working:

```
rewrite ^/myproject(/|$)$ /myproject/web last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks ok except for your root. The other paths should then change:

```
root /var/www/html/myserver/web;

location / {
  ...
}
location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
  ...
}
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
  ...
}

location ~ \.php$ {
...
```

You can see [the NGINX config docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) for reference.
If you want to use your existing config, then try this URL:

myserver.com/web

That might work.